# How do I add a plus symbol to a JS Counter-up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a plus symbol(+) that will appear after each counter-up results; for example currently I am having 150 as a result of the counter-up but I need the result to be 150+ and this should apply to all my elements

```js
// jQuery counterUp
$('[data-toggle="counter-up"]').counterUp({
  delay: 10,
  time: 1000,
});
```

```css
.skills .counters h2 {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: block;
  color: #eeaa0b;
}

.skills .counters p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #353535;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="skill" class="skills">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row counters">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
        <h2 data-toggle="counter-up">65</h2>
        <p>Our Staffs</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
        <h2 data-toggle="counter-up">190</h2>
        <p>Our Clients</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
        <h2 data-toggle="counter-up">150</h2>
        <p>Completed Projects</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
        <h2 data-toggle="counter-up">125</h2>
        <p>Running Projects</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Current results

65         190         150      125

Expected Result

65+       190+         150+     125+

Comment: Where's the code that adds the `+`s

Comment: Just add a `+` to the HTML after the `h2` elements...?

Comment: or use a css pseudo element using the data toggle as your selector

Comment: ^--- That's how I'd do it.  Using the `:after` pseudo-element with a `content` value of `"+"`

Comment: Take a look at my answer below, you'll see what @David suggested in action.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When I do that the plus appears below the counter-up instead of appearing after the numbers, can you kindly write your response as a code?

Comment: @iorgv Thanks it worked, I used after for it and the results were okay. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, my friend!

Comment: I did, there are other two who downgraded it.... "+1 (me) & -2 (others)"

Comment: Your question is pending editing approval, so you might get a few upvotes more after them.

Comment: @iorgv how can I center the plus symbol so that it appears like this 150+ because currently it appears to be on the lower side of the zero where the underscore is 150_ I need to push it up a bit.

Comment: You can tweak around with `top: -3px; position: relative;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, with a `:before` (if you want it to be beside it, otherwise `:after`) pseudo-element, like so:

```js
// jQuery counterUp
$('[data-toggle="counter-up"]').counterUp({
  delay: 10,
  time: 1000,
});
```

```css
.skills .counters h2 {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: block;
  color: #eeaa0b;
}

.skills .counters p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #353535;
}
/*new code from here*/
[data-toggle="counter-up"]:before {
  content: "+";
  font-size: 60px;
  color: #eeaa0b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="skill" class="skills">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row counters">

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
        <h2 data-toggle="counter-up">65</h2>
        <p>Our Staffs</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
        <h2 data-toggle="counter-up">190</h2>
        <p>Our Clients</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
        <h2 data-toggle="counter-up">150</h2>
        <p>Completed Projects</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3 col-6 text-center">
        <h2 data-toggle="counter-up">125</h2>
        <p>Running Projects</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```